# Using Self as a protocol requirements associated type in class

Tags: swift, protocols

This is my code:

```
protocol Jard {
    // Every Jard should have a food type refers to its own type
    associatedtype FoodType: Food<Self>
}

class LittleJard: Jard {
    // JardFood == Food<LittleJard> why does this not work?
    typealias FoodType = JardFood
}

class Food<AnyFood> {

}

class JardFood: Food<LittleJard> {

}
```

Compile error:

> Type 'LittleJard' does not conform to protocol 'Jard'

Why is this the case? From what I see, `JardFood` fulfills the requirement of `FoodType` in `LittleJard`.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, just filed [SR-10712](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-10712).

Comment: @Hamish hahaha, I'll close SR-10711 in that case…

Comment: Note that in this specific case, it shouldn't work, since `Food<LittleJard>` does not equal `Food<Self>` in the case of all subclasses of `JardFood`. But even if you fix that, by simplifying this to use structs and `final` classes, it doesn't work.

Comment: @RobNapier Hah, spooky timing there! Ignore my previous (now deleted) comment where I said a protocol's `Self` refers to the static conforming type, that's not correct – it does indeed refer to the dynamic type and therefore you're right in saying that OP's code shouldn't compile. Though in investigating, I managed to find a hole in the type system [SR-10713](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-10713) :)